# PSCP command not found in PuTTY

Tags: python, windows, putty, pscp

I'm trying to copy a file from a server, and since I'm using PuTTY I've read that using pscp is best. I've added the directory to pscp.exe to my path (C:\ProgramFiles\PuTTY), but when I try to use it I receive this:

`-bash: pscp: command not found`

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Edit: I also used pscp in the Windows command prompt, it gives me the exact same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video ended up showing me the solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1Tqr7Wk5aU&ab_channel=TonyTeachesTech

I was writing `pscp`, when I should've put `pscp -P 22`